# Remote support software Linux to windows, like teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop

I am  need  a free  Remote support software.

It needs to be painless for the people I'm supporting.

I'm a sys admin / help-desk engineer who supports Windows and Mac end users. Our company is in the middle of changing over Remote support software from Cisco WebEx to Logmein Rescue. So at the moment we have no proper support software and have all been asked to use Join.me for the cross over period. Join.me only works on PC and Mac and I'm running opensuse 12.1, my boss is fine with me using Linux as long as it doesn't hinder my work, which it hasn't until now, as WebEx ran fine.

I have been using teamviewer for the last week and its been great although now Teamviewer has blocked me because they suspect that I'm using it commercially and I should pay to do that. If teamviewer was £30 quid I'd pay but its £600 and I'm not willing to pay that for the month that I will need it.

Is there any alternative for Linux, it needs to be easy for the other side; i.e. go to this website, download this, click run, what's the ID, done.

I know VNC is free but you have to open up your router config find the port forward section add this port. It is not painless for the people I support.

Comment: in worst case you can install a virtual windows using virtualbox  or may be  wine can help you ( the program not the liquid ;-) )

Comment: @sherif Yes that is what I've had to do at the moment, its a good workaround but I can't help but feel there should be a more native way. +1

Answer (score 2):

Many (if not all) VNC implementations support listening mode, where the VNC client is started in listening mode and acts as a TCP server.

Next launch the VNC server on the customer machine, configured to connect as a TCP client to the given VNC server IP.

Comment: Thanks, That would require port forwards on our end, and my boss would rather me reinstall windows than do me a favour.

Answer (score 0):

[Micogo](http://www.mikogo.com/), is working great under Wine (as i can see now, they even have a native app for Linux so it is better), and it is very easy to use, (i don't know about the freeness of it but it has a free path of some kind). You just need to configure it at the option tab of the client to present the desktop to you and you are done.

and you have the [Crossloop](http://www.crossloop.com/), which is also simple to use ( i don't have any experience just heard about it).

Comment: I'llbe checking this out today thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

We use [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/).  It has to be installed in a Windows environment but then you can connect via Linux.  If you have a few customers to service during your down time you can download a trial that you can use for a month.

Comment: Hi ray what do you mean has to be installed in a windows environment, is there server software that needs installing and then the Linux box connects to the server?

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to followup on this.  But yes, ScreenConnect needs to be installed on a Windows server and then your Linux machine connects to that server.  Pretty straightforward.  Let me know if it worked for you.